# Which regression method or time-series analysis should I use?

Tags: time-series, regression, stata

This might be a very simple question for some of you, but I am new at quantitative analysis, and I will start watching YouTube tutorials according to your answers.

For my **independent variable**, I have country-level and yearly data (2000-2020) about repression. For each country, repression takes any values between -5 to 5 (including 0.78, -3.41, etc.)

I have country-level and yearly data (2000-2020) about terrorist incidents for my **dependent variable**. For each country, it takes any interval values (0, 1, 10, 125).

Which regression method should I use? Should I use time-series analysis? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a statistician so take my answer with caution. Time series is one of the more complex aspects to statistics, and there is really no simple good way to do it. If you are new to statistics I would stay away from it. I have studied it for years and still am unsure about major elements of it. Is this for a class and if it is, will your instructor insist on time series. If not I would not use it.

In deciding if you can use regression rather than time series a number of questions have to be answered. First, is there a trend in the data, non-stationarity. There are tests (and problems with those tests) for this. If there are trends in the data regular regression will generate errors unless they are cointegrated (and if they are cointegrated specific forms of regression have to be used). You will get relationships driven by the trends between the IV and DV that don't actually exist.

A second question is if the impact of the IV has its effect immediately, in which case regression is possible ignoring the issue above, or if the effect occurs at some point in the future. If the later happens you have to deal with lags. You also, as a separate issue, have to deal with autocorrlation which will distort your standard errors. One solution is special standard errors but that only works in some cases.

That is a tiny piece of the issue, mainly done to explain why time series is not for someone new to quantitative methods. All you can reasonably due is run regression and understand these type of limits. IF you have some theoretical reason to believe that the relationship between the IV and DV changes over time, you might run the regression in pieces, run it for specific time frames, and see if the results vary (again there are formal tests for this).